# Magento2 Admin Grid Product Image Display

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1

I need to display product image in admin grid view. I tried below code.

```
class Image extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{ 

public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row) {


        //$this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Product')->getImageUrl($product);
        //$helper = $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image')->init($product,'cart_page_product_thumbnail') ->constrainOnly(true)->keepAspectRatio(true)->keepFrame(false)->setImageFile($product->getImage())->getUrl();

       $id=$row->getId();
       $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
       $store = $objectManager->get('Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface')->getStore();
       $product       = $objectManager->get('Magento\Catalog\Model\Product')->load($id);


        $imageHelper  = $objectManager->get('\Magento\Catalog\Helper\Image');
        $image_url = $imageHelper->init($product, 'product_thumbnail_image')->setImageFile($product->getFile())->resize(100, 100)->getUrl();
        $prod_name = $product->getName();
       //$product->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('small_image');
       if($image_url){
        $html='<img class="admin__control-thumbnail" data-bind="attr: {src: $col.getSrc($row()), alt: $col.getAlt($row())}" src="'.$image_url.'" alt="'.$prod_name.'">';
       }
       else{

        $placeholderImageUrl = $imageHelper->getDefaultPlaceholderUrl('thumbnail');
        $html = '<img class="admin__control-thumbnail" data-bind="attr: {src: $col.getSrc($row()), alt: $col.getAlt($row())}" src="'.$placeholderImageUrl.'" alt="'.$prod_name.'">';

       }

        return $html;
    }

}
```

I am rending this image to grid as follows.

```
 protected function _prepareColumns()
    {
        $this->addColumn(
            'entity_id',
            [
                'header' => __('ID'),
                'type' => 'number',
                'index' => 'entity_id',
                'header_css_class' => 'col-id',
                'column_css_class' => 'col-id'
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn('image',
           [
                'header' => __('Image'),
                'type' => 'text',
                'align' => 'center',
                'filter' => false,
                'sortable' => false,
                'renderer' => 'My\Module\Block\Adminhtml\mproducts\Renderer\Image',
            ]);
        $this->addColumn(
            'name',
            [
                'header' => __('Name'),
                'index' => 'name',
            ]
        );
}
```

I am getting same image for all the products. Whats wrong in my code?

Comment: I tried to print $product->getFile(); it is printing same for all the products.

Comment: 'index' => 'image', define in grid.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your grid.php define like below

```
$this->addColumn(
    'image',
    array(
        'header' => __('Image'),
        'index' => 'image',
        'renderer'  => '\Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Modulename\Grid\Renderer\Image',
    )
);
```

Create `Image.php` under

> \Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Modulename\Grid\Renderer\

and paste below code

```
namespace Vendorname\Modulename\Block\Adminhtml\Modulename\Grid\Renderer;

class Image extends \Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Grid\Column\Renderer\AbstractRenderer
{
    protected $_storeManager;


    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Backend\Block\Context $context,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,      
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;        
    }


    public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        $img;
        $mediaDirectory = $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getBaseUrl(
           \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface::URL_TYPE_MEDIA
       );
        if($this->_getValue($row)!=''):
            $imageUrl = $mediaDirectory.$this->_getValue($row);
            $img='<img src="'.$imageUrl.'" width="100" height="100"/>';
        else:
            $img='<img src="'.$mediaDirectory.'Modulename/no-img.jpg'.'" width="100" height="100"/>';
        endif;
        return $img;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Its worked perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

How to do if I want to show the thumbnail (or base image) under "images and videos"?
I have this similar code for thumbnails in grid but I want to show it under images and videos aswell.